# How can I make the header's border/other content not overlap the img on the left?

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="container">

            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="img">
            </div>

            <div id="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <div id="mainContent">
                Content
                </div>

                <div id="imgOne">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>

                <div id="imgTwo">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>

                <div id="imgThree">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: left;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

#nav {
    clear: left;
}

#content {

}
```

How it currently looks.

[image] This is what it looks like right now. I would like the header to not be overlapping and still stay centered in the page, how can I do that?

Sorry if the post is sloppy, first post here & new to coding.

Comment: what is the expected output, can you show as image?

Comment: This is what I want the finished website to look like, http://puu.sh/kJJF7/0f422c95ad.png ..

Comment: I'm using borders just to see the space it is taking. and I may plan on adding background colors behind the header but not overlapping the image on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in so many ways dependent of how everything else on the page should behave.

Below sample just show a way to fix the header issue.

The to the "header" added "margin" and "padding" make sure the header text is center to page and as well not overlap the image.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: left;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: 156px;
    padding-right: 156px;
}

#nav {
    clear: left;
}

#content {

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

            <!-- Header -->
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="img">
            </div>

            <div id="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">nav</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <div id="mainContent">
                Content
                </div>

                <div id="imgOne">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>

                <div id="imgTwo">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>

                <div id="imgThree">
                    <img src="img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
```